# Left label - Right Label using Autolayout (Swift)

Tags: swift, autolayout

I am using autolayout in swift and I am curious if there is a better way of doing this.

Basically I am positioning a left label and a right label. Like so...

[Left Label  -------------------- Right Label]

Here is what I have done.

```
let bottomView = UIView(frame : CGRectMake(0, 150, 380, 25))
bottomView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
self.view.addSubview(bottomView)

let leftLabel = UILabel()
leftLabel.text = "Left"

let rightLabel = UILabel()
rightLabel.text = "Right Label"
rightLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right

let views = [
    "left" : leftLabel,
    "right" : rightLabel
]

for (key,view) in views {
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    bottomView.addSubview(view)
    // It seems like there should be better way of handling this
    self.view.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[\(key)]|",
            options: [NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllCenterX],
            metrics:nil,
            views:views
        )
    )

}

// why does the right "spacing" have to be 10 and the left only has to be 5?
self.view.addConstraints(
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
        "H:|-5-[left]-(>=0)-[right]-10-|",
        options: [NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeftToRight],
        metrics:nil,
        views:views)
)
```

1) I feel like there is a better way of handling the Vertical section.
2) Why does the right side spacing have to be "10" to match the left side's "5"

Comment: Are you checking on an iPhone 6?  `bottomView` doesn't appear to have any constraints and is 380pt wide.  Since the phone is 375pt wide, your view would overhang by 5pt meaning you need a 10pt margin on the right to match the 5pt on the left.

Comment: @BrianNickel - Thanks that was the issue with the 10pt margin issue.